# How to implement monotonically/sequentially increasing counter of 20 bytes in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to implement sequentially increasing counter of fixed number of bytes (let us say 20 bytes) to represent a positive id.  I can use a byte array like

```
int size = 20;
byte[] bytes = new byte[size]; //initializes to 0
```

But I donot understand how I can add 1 to least significant bit of bytes[0] where carry-on would go towards most significant bits.

1) I reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253298/adding-1-to-binary-byte-array) for addition, but that solution is adding to lowest byte and not bit

2) java bytes are signed by default. But I am looking for positive counter, hence I need 20 bytes of unsigned bytes

Comment: You don't need to do it per bit. Just keep adding to a byte until all its bits are 1 (value equals -1, because bytes are signed) and then you increment the next byte in the array. You can also use BigInteger, but because it is immutable, it creates a new copy when you add a number to it which may not be what you want.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: Also, I am looking for only unsigned counter, but bytes are by default signed in Java (updated the question)

Comment: You can just treat the bytes as unsigned. There are a few things you need to think about (like, if you want to compare it to a constant value, you need to mask: `if ((bytes[x] & 0xff) == 255) { bytes[x] = 0; } else { bytes[x]++; break; }`

Comment: Whatever for? If all you need is a counter to increment, the range of a 64 bit integer - which java provides out of the box - should be plenty. For instance, even if you were to increment your `long` a billion times per second, it would take nearly 300 years until the counter overflows ... (because `2**63/1e9/86400/365 = 292`)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting exercise. I had to narrow the size down to 8 and use short as a working type due to the sign, but apparently it works. However I did not test it exhaustively and should you need to use this - for reasons I can not grasp - do test it and make sure it does what you want.

```
package bytex;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Bytex {

    private static long[] power = new long[8];
    private static short[] shorts = new short[8];
    private static byte[] bytes = new byte[8];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int x = 7, y = 0; x >= 0; x--, y += 8) {
            power[x] = (long) Math.pow(2, y);
        }

        long value = 9223372036854775806L;
        setNumber(value);
        printBytes();
        printShorts();
        System.out.println(getNumber());

        value = getNumber();
        value += 1;
        setNumber(value);
        printBytes();
        printShorts();
        System.out.println(getNumber());
    }

    private static long getNumber() {
        long number = 0L;
        for (int x = shorts.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
            String binary = Long.toBinaryString(shorts[x]);
            number += Short.parseShort(binary, 2) * power[x];
        }
        return number;
    }

    private static void setNumber(long newValue) {
        Arrays.fill(shorts, (byte) 0);
        char binTemp[] = new char[64];
        for (int x = 0; x < binTemp.length; x++) {
            binTemp[x] = '0';
        }

        String binary = Long.toBinaryString(newValue);
        int y = binTemp.length - 1;
        for (int x = binary.length() - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
            binTemp[y--] = binary.charAt(x);
        }

        for (int x = 0, ini = 0; x < shorts.length; x++, ini += 8) {
            shorts[x] = Short.parseShort(new String(binTemp, ini, 8), 2);
            bytes[x] = (byte) (shorts[x] & 0xff);
        }

    }

    private static void printBytes() {
        for (short aByte : bytes) {
            System.out.printf("0x%02X \t", aByte);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void printShorts() {
        for (short aShort : shorts) {
            System.out.printf("0x%04X \t", aShort);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```